# Is the Degenerate skill name used as a noun or a verb?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

In [episode 9](https://www.crunchyroll.com/that-time-i-got-reincarnated-as-a-slime/episode-9-attack-of-the-ogres-778583) of *That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime* (time code 7:44 at Crunchyroll) Rimuru uses a new skill he got from Shizu, called **Degenerate**.

[image: Rimuru in Veldora's cave]

> I wanted to test out Degenerate

I think this may be an awkward translation.  First, its pronunciation is different between its noun and verb forms, with the verb using a long "a" sound in the final syllable.  Second, most other skill names are nouns (Body Armor, Paralysis Breath, etc. -- an exception being Mimic). But as a noun, the word "degenerate" does not fit at all.  The in game description is that it uses unification and separation to form a new skill from pre-existing ones.  "Degenerate" as a verb can sort of fit, though not well.

**Is this just a poor translation, and is it a verb or a noun?** A better term for what is being described would be "Recomposition".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some minor spoilers ahead.

I think it is a **noun**. Its other name is 'Deviant', which is used as a noun or an adjective. Furthermore, it was noted in the [wiki](http://tensura.wikia.com/wiki/Deviant) that

> The kanji for Deviant translate to both Shapeshifter and Deviant (Degenerate or Pervert)

which

> is where the pun comes from when Rimuru teases the spirit of Shizue inside him at a comedic panel of the manga at the end of the chapter.

From these two translations, it is also used as a **noun**.

Degenerate, according to Wikipedia, is someone who has *fallen from a previous state* whereas deviant is something that departs from the norm. The skill releases properties *inherent* to the target, which is quiet similar to what happens when one becomes a *degenerate* or if someone becomes a *deviant*.